# filter child model based on parent model boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have written a scope to filter out results where 'free entry = true'. I want the scope to apply to a Products database as well as its child , job_product.

Product.rb

```
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  title            :string(255)
  ............
#  free_entry       :boolean          default(FALSE)

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :not_free_entry_scope, -> { where(free_entry: false) }
  has_many :job_products, dependent: :destroy,
                     inverse_of: :product
```

job_product.rb

```
# Table name: job_products
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  job_id       :integer
#  product_id   :integer
#  quantity     :integer          default(1)
#  frozen_cache :text
#  created_at   :datetime
#  updated_at   :datetime
#

class JobProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  # associations
  belongs_to :product, inverse_of: :job_products
  scope :not_free_entry_scope, -> { where(free_entry: false) }
```

I know it works, I can scope it in rails console like so,

```
Product.where("free_entry = true")
```

I can scope the product model successfully, however when I try to apply the same scope to the job_product model, and use it in the controller it spits an error

```
Unknown column 'job_products.free_entry' in 'where clause'
```

How do I refine the scope to a child of the parent class.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is because you're using a `Object.property` as a key in a hash, that's not valid syntax.  What you need to do is tell it to join the Products table, and then you can re-use the Product's scope with [`merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge).

Try this:

```
class JobProduct
  ...
  scope :not_free, -> { joins(:product).merge(Product.not_free_entry_scope) }
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks @NickVeys, that makes sense, but I am left with the error
Association named 'products' was not found on JobProduct; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: so i changed it to 

  scope :not_free, -> { joins(:product).merge(Product.not_free_entry_scope) }

Comment: Nick thats awesome. Thank you. Can you give me a bit more info on using a key in a hash. My knowledge gap between what ruby is (i understand a hash) and its implementation of rails is sparse. Again, thank you

Comment: Well when you say `where(Product.free_entry: false)`, you're saying `where({ Product.free_entry: false })`.  The shorthand hash syntax you use (the `key: value` kind) doesn't work with that, instead you could say: `where(Product.free_entry => false)`, but then you'll get an undefined method error after that, since `Product` doesn't have a `free_entry` method on the class.

Comment: That makes sense. Cheers. I'll edit my question to make it more precise. that was a very helpful answer